# Creating image from view crashes in renderInContext on iOS 9 only

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I'm trying to create an image from a UIView to create a blurring effect on it. I'm capturing the image like so:

```
CGFloat scale = 1.0;
if([[UIScreen mainScreen]respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    CGFloat tmp = [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];
    if (tmp > 1.5) {
        scale = 2.0;
    }
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, scale);


[[view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return screenshot;
```

However, in iOS 9, this fails on the `renderInContext` step. It gives the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'sublayer with non-finite position [-23 inf]'
```

So, I've got a few questions.

1. Does anyone know why I'm running into an inf position in one of my layers? This only happens on iOS 9, and only in one particular scenario, and I'm not exactly sure what's different about this scenario from all the others around our app.
2. Is there any way I can workaround this and still get an image from a view? We need a custom blur with a radius of 3, so using the VisualEffectView doesn't seem to be able to work. Which brings me to...
3. Is there any way that is not too hacky to change the radius of a VisualEffectView blur? It would only need to work in iOS 9, but the default radius is way too blurred for this specific blur we have, so using VisualEffectViews without modifying the radius isn't ideal.

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: how did u create the uiview? and when/where r u calling the above code ?

Comment: This code is called every time we show one of our custom modals -- they animate up and appear as a separate window on screen with the rest of the background darkened and blurred. I get the view by simply accessing the view of whichever ViewController is presenting the modal at the time.

Comment: did u check the view bounds? What are the view bounds ?

Comment: The view bounds should be the size of the screen. And these bounds work perfectly in the exact same situation on iOS 8 and below -- they just start acting up once iOS 9 was introduced.

Comment: where did u create the uiview ?

Comment: Whenever the user navigates to the page where the modal can be presented. It's just the view of the view controller presenting the modal, so it's created as the user hits each page where a modal can be presented (whether the modal is presented or not)

Comment: Unrelated but much of your code isn't needed. Get rid of all the code related to `scale` and simply pass `0.0` to the `scale` parameter of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. And checking to see if `UIScreen` supports `scale` is pointless since it was added in iOS 4.0.

Comment: Log `view.bounds` just before calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.

Comment: (0 0; 768 1024) when it crashes and the same for when it doesn't crash. And also a lot of this is legacy code, this project has been around for a long time -- this category probably hasn't been touched in 3 or 4 years, maybe more.

Comment: I will suggest to NSLog all the subviews frames in a loop overtime to check the odd scenario. Perhaps helpful

Comment: So I've definitely found 12 places in my layer subtree which have inf as a y coordinate. If I can narrow down where that's happening I'll update my post. It's only appearing on iOS 9....